# How to use avalondock in wpf

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

Hey I got a little problem with the avalondock.

Im trying to change my view from basically a grid with two columns (one rather large section on the left and a rather small one with two little windows on the right). I want to left one to be the "background" of my window and the two small windows on the right should be dockable whereever the user wants to dock them. This is what i tried:

```
<DockPanel>
    <Grid>
        <avalonDock:DockingManager Name="dockManager">
<avalonDock:LayoutRoot>
                <avalonDock:LayoutRoot.LeftSide>
                    <avalonDock:LayoutAnchorSide>
                        <avalonDock:LayoutAnchorGroup>
                            <avalonDock:LayoutAnchorable Title="Editor"
                                                         ContentId="Editor"
                                                         CanClose="False"
                                                         CanHide="False"
                                                         CanAutoHide="False"
                                                         CanFloat="False"
                                                         AutoHideMinWidth="200">                                    
                                <ContentControl>
                                    <GroupBox Grid.RowSpan="3"
                                              Grid.Column="0"
                                              Header="Editor"
                                              Visibility="{Binding IsFileOpen}">
                                        <ContentControl Content="{Binding EditorViewModel}" />
                                    </GroupBox>
                                </ContentControl>

                            </avalonDock:LayoutAnchorable>
                        </avalonDock:LayoutAnchorGroup>
                    </avalonDock:LayoutAnchorSide>
                </avalonDock:LayoutRoot.LeftSide>
<avalonDock:LayoutPanel>
                    <avalonDock:LayoutDocumentPane DockWidth="0.8*" />

                    <avalonDock:LayoutAnchorablePaneGroup Orientation="Vertical"
                                                          DockWidth="400">
                        <avalonDock:LayoutAnchorablePane>
                            <avalonDock:LayoutAnchorable Title="Tools"
                                                         ContentId="Elements"
                                                         CanClose="False"
                                                         CanHide="False">
                                <ContentControl Content="{Binding ElementsViewModel}" />
                            </avalonDock:LayoutAnchorable>
                        </avalonDock:LayoutAnchorablePane>

                        <avalonDock:LayoutAnchorablePane>
                            <avalonDock:LayoutAnchorable Title="Properties"
                                                         ContentId="Properties"
                                                         CanClose="False"
                                                         CanHide="False">
                                <GroupBox Header="Properties">
                                    <GroupBox.Resources>
                                        <ResourceDictionary>
                                            <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
                                                <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/ET.Usage.Acp.Apps.EventDrivenPetriNet.Editor;component/View/DataTemplates/PropertiesTemplates.xaml" />
                                                <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/ET.Usage.Acp.Apps.EventDrivenPetriNet.Editor;component/View/Styles/MainStyles.xaml" />
                                            </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
                                        </ResourceDictionary>
                                    </GroupBox.Resources>
                                    <Border Background="{StaticResource ResourceKey=TabControl_BackgroundBrush_Base}"
                                            BorderBrush="{StaticResource ResourceKey=TabItem_BorderBrush_Selected}"
                                            BorderThickness="1,1,1,1">
                                        <Border Margin="8"
                                                BorderBrush="{StaticResource ResourceKey=TabPage_InnerBorderBrushDark}"
                                                BorderThickness="1"
                                                CornerRadius="3">
                                            <Border Margin="0"
                                                    BorderBrush="{StaticResource ResourceKey=TabPage_InnerBorderBrushBright}"
                                                    BorderThickness="1"
                                                    CornerRadius="2"
                                                    Padding="2,2,3,3">
                                                <ContentControl MinHeight="80"
                                                                Content="{Binding PropertiesViewModel}"
                                                                ContentTemplateSelector="{StaticResource PropertiesTemplateSelector}" />
                                            </Border>
                                        </Border>
                                    </Border>
                                </GroupBox>
                            </avalonDock:LayoutAnchorable>
                        </avalonDock:LayoutAnchorablePane>
                    </avalonDock:LayoutAnchorablePaneGroup>
                </avalonDock:LayoutPanel>
            </avalonDock:LayoutRoot>
                    </avalonDock:DockingManager>
    </Grid>
</DockPanel>
```

So as you can see I tried to add my editor view on the left side (LayoutRoot.LeftSide) and then two dockable views on the right side (LayoutPanel).

The docking windows are working as expected, but the editor view is just another Dockingwindow aswell. At runtime I can say: Dock as tabbed document or something like that, but this doesnt fix my problem because (even if i could do this at design time) I still end up with a tab, what I dont want (one reason is because the ContentControl will have multiple tabs again). I just want the editorview to be the background of my window, which cannot be floated etc.

thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I can't answer your specific question unfortunately but for me the best thing to do was to implement the Save Layout and Load Layout options on the DockingManager and then simply load the one you want by default on Application startup, it's a lot easier than messing around with the code, which for some reason seems impossibly difficult to tell what to do.